# Android ListView Button Listener Location

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener

I have a ListView with customized Adapter which includes a Button. I nmy activity I create this listview:

```
rListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_list_view);
RequestAdapter adapter = new RequestAdapter(RequestsListActivity.this, allRequests);
rListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And in my Adapter I have the following method in which I populate the items of the list:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_request, parent, false);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_origin);

        Button acceptRequestButton = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.acceptRequestButton);

        Request request = (Request) getItem(position);

        acceptRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
```

So I have a Button `acceptRequestButton` in each item of the list and I want to add a listener to them. Now do I have to add the listener in the `getView` method as seen above or in the activity with:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = ...
rListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

?

Comment: You have to add the listener in the `getView` method as shown above.

Comment: Doing `rListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener)` doesn't look good from the user point of view, because the whole list item will be "selected" on click. Besides, AFAIK, the click will be intercepted by the list item and won't be passed to the button listener. Use the listener as per your code.